# 2D map for mobile game

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine, export, camera

I'm currently working on a 2D map for mobile game,which has to contain the Great Wall of China all across the map and of course a colorful,seasoning,cartoon background with many nature assets-rocks,trees,lakes and stuff.My original plan was to stick only to Photoshop and Wirawiri Map Builder,but I was having trouble with the Great Wall,so I jumped to Blender and made a 3D version of it with some details like towers,but now I'm stuck with how to proceed.
   When I import the Great Wall .obj file to photoshop it gets too blurry, no matter if I scale it or zoom it. Any ideas why this happens?I'm also using tree[d] for Blender to generate some trees and I assume I will have the same problem when I import the .obj files to Photoshop.
   I'd really appreciate any kind of advices,hints or software about the workflow of creating a game map since it's the first time I do such thing.

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand due to lack of formatting. Most people might go tl;dr after a third of your posting, so maybe you should edit it and use paragraphs to order the content.

Comment: I have no experience with importing obj to fotoshop, but when the diffuse map of a texture gets blurry it almost always has to do with the texture's size. Maybe a screenshot or two would help your question? Also: Is your 2D map in front view or top-down?

Answer (score 1):

[image: On the left is the obj import and the ground texture broke to complete white for no reason.On the right is a render version with 1 light source so I got that shadow.]

[image: Here's a second try on importing the obj]

The camera should be from top-down with slight rotation as in the 1st image(not completely orthographic top view)